# How to plot for each day of week for each individual category in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a sample dataframe like the one shown below:

```
Cat      Mon  Tues  Weds  Thurs  Fri  Sat  Sun
red      23    34    1     10    30   500   9 
yellow   23    34    11    31    22   20    9 
blue     23    34    123   10    412  4     9 
black    23    34    11    321   53   7     9 

etc......
```

I am trying to graph the occurrences of each day of the week for each respective 'cat' columns. So plot the count of the number of occurrences for each day of the week plot them on subplots.

So for example in the above dataframe there would be 4 subplots. For the each suplot, there would we 7 bars representing the counts for the respective day.

If anyone has any suggestions it'd be awesome, thanks.

Comment: How about: `df.groupby('Cat').plot(kind='bar')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `T` and then `plot.bar()`:

```
df.T.plot.bar(subplots=True, layout=(2,2), figsize=(15,10));
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: OK, that's because in your example there are 4 rows, so I used (2,2). Try it with `layout=(7,2)`

Comment: @annarashed use `sharey=True` argument. JoshFriedlander I'm pointing to first 2 subplots the labels are missing `Mon, Tue...`

Comment: @meW it's almost the same: use `sharex=False`

Comment: @annarashed If you have `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, you could try `plt.tight_layout()` on the line below

Answer (score 2):

Well, an answer has already been accepted, but I thought i'd contribute this solution anyway. It's always nice to see multiple solutions to the same problem.

I like using matplotlib to do the plotting directly as it's easier to tweak the figure to be exactly as we desire. I also like this solution as it's easy to colour the cats sensibly (ie using red bars to plot the red cats)

Let's start by importing your data:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO("""
Cat      Mon  Tues  Weds  Thurs  Fri  Sat  Sun
red      23    34    1     10    30   500   9 
yellow   23    34    11    31    22   20    9 
blue     23    34    123   10    412  4     9 
black    23    34    11    321   53   7     9
"""), header=1)
```

Next we make the plot, making sure the plots are coloured sensibly (ie, the red cat counts aren't represented by blue bars):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)

color = ['C3', 'C8', 'C0', 'k']
ax = ax.reshape(4)
for i in range(4):
    ax[i].bar(np.r_[:7], df.T[i][1:], color=color[i])
    ax[i].set_xticks(np.r_[:7])
    ax[i].set_xticklabels(['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'], rotation=90)

fig.tight_layout()
```

All this gave me the following:

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, +1 - how did you get those snazzy looking charts?

Comment: Thanks. That's the [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) style, you can use it with ```plt.style.use('seaborn')```